# How can I get the name of a class from inside the base class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a base class BaseModel, and and a subclass SubModel. I want to define a function inside BaseModel that will return the string name of the class. I have this working for instances of BaseClass, but if I make an SubModel instance, the function still returns "BaseModel". Here is the code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class BaseModel
    {
        public string GetModelName()
        {
            return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.Name;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class SubModel : BaseModel
    {

    }
}
```

And I would like this call:

```
SubModel test = new SubModel();
string name = test.GetModelName();
```

To return "SubModel". Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to override the method in your subclass.

Comment: No override necessary, use this.GetType().Name.... but I'm worried if you need to worry about the name of subclass type.

Comment: Just call GetType().Name in the subclass;

Comment: Anthony has it. Thanks a bunch. And don't worry about me too much, just tooling around with reflection, not doing any serious work here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public string GetModelName()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
}

class SubModel : BaseModel
{

}

SubModel test = new SubModel();
string name = test.GetModelName();
```

This is also possible:

```
string name = (test as BaseModel).GetModelName();
string name = ((BaseModel)test).GetModelName();

//both return "SubModel"
```